# When trying to get a model field value i get DeferredAttribute object Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello so basically i have a profile model that keeps track of points. And i group those profiles into groups as students. So basically in the groups i have a method going through all of the students in the group and returning a list of points but it's intended to be sum(), (since im getting an error i tried a list to debug). How do i get the actuall value instead of the object? This is the code:

```
class profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def addPoints(self, amount):
        self.points += amount

    def subtractPoints(self, amount):
        self.points -= amount

    def changePoints(self, amount):
        self.points += amount

class skupine(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('#52A2D9', 'Modra'),
        ('#8ec641', 'Zelena'),
        ('#f3c12f', 'Rumena'),
        ('#e2884c', 'Oranžna'),
        ('#f37358', 'Rdeča'),
        ('#b460a5', 'Vijolična')
    )

    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teacherToSkupina')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desciption = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=choices)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(profil, related_name='studentsToSkupina')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_total_points(self):
        return list(profil.points for items in self.students.all())
                        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "skupine"
```

What i get when i call the method :

```
>>> s.get_total_points()
[<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03D957D0>]
```

What i want:

```
[4,5,2,3,6,1,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `s` is an instance of `skupine` class. In that case, if you need the list of points from related `profil` objects, you should do the following:

```
def get_total_points(self):
    return [student.points for student in self.students.all()]
```

and, if you need the sum of points, use sum built-in function:

```
def get_total_points(self):
    return sum(student.points for student in self.students.all())
```

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I have seen that i haven't expressed the point of the question. I need to get the actual field values instead of the object location.